# Not able to generate lttng traces from java sample

Tags: java, lttng

I'm executing java sample for logging on Lttng tracing session. For this I am using lttng-ust-jul & java logging library.

I followed all steps given here: [lttng java tutorial](http://lttng.org/blog/2015/05/12/tutorial-java-tracing/)
But still **lttng view** outputs nothing.. means nothing got traced over session files.

Here are the detailed steps that I followed and their respective outputs:

Test.Java:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import org.lttng.ust.agent.LTTngAgent;

public class Test
{
    private static final int answer = 42;

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception
    {
        // create a logger
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("jello");

        // call this as soon as possible (before logging)
        LTTngAgent lttngAgent = LTTngAgent.getLTTngAgent();

        logger.setLevel(Level.FINEST);

        // log at will!
        logger.info("some info");
        logger.warning("some warning");
        Thread.sleep(500);
        logger.finer("finer information; the answer is " + answer);
        Thread.sleep(123);
        logger.severe("error!");

        // not mandatory, but cleaner
        lttngAgent.dispose();
    }
}
```

Commands :

lttng create newSession

```
Session newSession created.
Traces will be written in /home/XXX/lttng-traces/newSession-20160308-005717
```

lttng enable-event -j -a

```
All JUL events are enabled in channel channel0
```

lttng start

```
Tracing started for session newSession
```

javac -cp /usr/share/java/liblttng-ust-agent.jar Test.java

java -cp /usr/share/java/liblttng-ust-agent.jar:. Test

```
Mar 08, 2016 12:58:54 AM Test main
INFO: some info
Mar 08, 2016 12:58:54 AM Test main
WARNING: some warning
Mar 08, 2016 12:58:55 AM Test main
SEVERE: error!
```

lttng stop

```
Waiting for data availability.
Tracing stopped for session newSession
```

lttng view

```
Trace directory: /home/XXX/lttng-traces/newSession-20160308-005717
```

"lttng view" command's desired output should be similar to

```
[22:46:14.940125765] (+0.000004944) XXX : { cpu_id = 8 }, { my_string_field = "some info" }
[22:46:14.940131743] (+0.000005978) XXX : { cpu_id = 8 }, { my_string_field = "some warning" }
...
```

I tried from root user as well.. so the possibility that user don't have rights to write on the files can be excluded.

Also, C++ sample is running fine ie. sample is able to trace data. So we can even exclude the possibility that lttng is configured incorrectly.

```
Machine Configuration:
Ubuntu 15.04
lttng version - 2.7
```

How can I proceed further to debug this issue with jul?

Comment: debug what? You haven't described any actual problem, you just showed code, and the result of running that code. Where's the description of what you expected and how the actual result deviates from that?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - logger in Java file should trace to some lttng session trace file. Desired output I posted in my ques now. Please check and let me know if still some issue..

Comment: it is - please start your post with an actual an problem statement. "I'm trying to have my logger trace to an lttng session, but instead of seeing it log to my session, logging information that should show up doesn't. Specifically, in the following code: ..., line XYZ runs without errors but does not lead to a log in ..." etc. etc. Describe the problem, don't just dump code and assume that's enough information for people to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do to debug the problem a bit is to issue a `lttng list -j` command during one of the `Thread.sleep()` calls, and perhaps increasing their duration a bit. The "jello" logger you registered should show up in the list. If not, then you'd know the problem is probably with the Java agent, not with the UST side of things.

I would also suggest taking a look at the [git master](http://git.lttng.org/?p=lttng-ust.git;a=summary) version of LTTng-UST. A big rework of the Java agent was done. The previous version used weird reflection mechanisms to load the JUL and log4j plugins, and would silently fail in some error cases. This may be what you are experiencing here.

The new version, which should be released with LTTng 2.8, introduces a new API which is much more explicit. The application controls the log handlers directly, and common errors (cannot find Java classes, cannot find native library, etc.) should get reported immediately. You can take a look at the new API in the updated [examples](http://git.lttng.org/?p=lttng-ust.git;a=blob;f=doc/examples/java-jul/Hello.java;h=cb9f24b198fc7be376b9a2d91f541e9e9b4e0e4e;hb=1820ea46d07f578495ff6258102038355c1529dd).

In all cases, make sure you use the same versions of the Java agent, lttng-ust, and lttng-tools (either 2.7 or 2.8/master), and that no other version exists on the system to avoid compatibility errors.

Comment: lttng list -j  : outputs None. And I'm using the latest release from ppa ie. 2.7 . So what should i do now to make this work?